# How to state if my VAR model is valid?

Tags: r, time-series, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression

Looking online I found two way to select a VAR model, using ar() and VARselect specifically this is what I get with my data:

```
var.auto <- ar(data, order.max = 10)
> var.auto$aic
        0         1         2         3         4         5 
40.340978  2.861890  0.000000  2.263284  9.561082 14.239344 
        6         7         8         9        10 
19.067029 32.315523 24.326890 42.272378 57.660436


VARselect(data, lag.max=10, type="const")$selection
 AIC(n)  HQ(n)  SC(n) FPE(n) 
     2      1      1      2
```

In orther to test my model I used to following tests:

```
serial.test(x = varmodel)
arch.test(varmodel)
normality.test(varmodel)
```

As result a VAR(2) model should be the suitable one.
Anyway I tried both VAR(1) and VAR(2).

But for each of them I get a p-value lower, way lower, than the significance level 0.05! What am I doing wrong?

add:

I have also noticed that the FPE value is really high

```
> VARselect(dataTest, lag.max=10, type="const")$criteria

                      1            2            3            4            5            
    AIC(n)     11.91503     11.91233     11.91516     11.92219     11.92685     
    HQ(n)      11.96800     12.00944     12.05641     12.10759     12.15639     
    SC(n)      12.05484     12.16865     12.28799     12.41153     12.53270     
    FPE(n) 149497.18839 149093.74660 149517.50861 150575.52286 151281.85451 

    >
```

Comment: How many observations do you have and what is the dimension of the process you want to model as a Vector Autoregression?

Comment: I have 1077 obs and 5 different variables

Comment: When you say "I get a p-value lower, way lower, than the significance level 0.05", which test/coefficient/... are you referring to? I.e., what do the $\texttt{serial.text}, \texttt{arch.test}, \texttt{normality.test}$ functions correspond to?

Comment: I performed a Portmanteau test, JB-test, Skewness, Kurtosis

Comment: In that case, you are not doing anything wrong. It simply means that your errors are not normal (which honestly is not a surprise, but also is not needed for VAR models to be consistent - usually assuming that your errors are martingale difference sequences is enough), that the errors are still serially dependent (which indicates that you should try some higher-order VAR structure and see if that still happens - and that if it does, you should think about using a VARMA model instead). Personally, since it only induces 25/50 more parameters, I would compare to VAR(3) and VAR(4) first

Comment: Thanks Jeremias.
I have tried already higher orders and the results are bad as well.
I tried anyway to predict the forecasts using the VAR(2) model and they are pretty bad as expected.
What should be my conclusions then?
I am also asked to provide a MARIMA model, that so far looks way better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69852/discussion-between-user158013-and-jeremias-k).

Comment: As mentioned in several earlier answers (see some [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:53690%20[var]%20is:answer)), information criteria and model diagnostics are not supposed to "agree". Information criteria balance out underfitting against overfitting, while diagnostic tests will show best results for overfit models. But for practical purposes, a balanced choice makes more sense. You can always overfit to the level that the diagnostic tests will tell you your model is fine, but then such a model will generalize poorly out of sample, and I think it is the latter that counts.